# Как можно объявить имя и тип переменной условно?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Возможно ли объявлять переменные условно в функциях или процедурах?

Например, можно ли сделать что-то такое:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_sales(in_year PLS_INTEGER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    IF condtion THEN
        variable_name_1 BINARY_FLOAT;
    ELSE
        variable_name_2 NUMBER;
    END;
BEGIN 
    NULL;
    -- логика функции 
END;
```

Если условие `condtion` выполнится, то нужно объявить переменную с именем `variable_name_1`, если нет, то вместо этой переменной нужно объявить другую переменную - `variable_name_2`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle PL/SQL Conditional Declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62589100/6571020) от участника [@Ashan Priyadarshana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5273203/ashan-priyadarshana)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62589100

Answer (score 2):

Условная компиляция ([Conditional Compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-DC23291F-006D-49C4-87DA-6B31F19F162A)) досупна с [версии 10g](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-conditional-compilation).

Пример:

```
create or replace procedure cctest as
$IF $$cctest_on $THEN
    var1 binary_float;
$ELSE
    var2 number;
$END
begin
$IF $$cctest_on $THEN
    var1 := 1.23E+004;
$ELSE
    var2 := 999;
$END
end cctest;
/
Procedure CCTEST compiled

alter procedure cctest compile PLSQL_CCFLAGS='cctest_on:true' reuse settings
/
Procedure CCTEST altered.
```

Так можно посмотреть исходный код последней компиляции:

```
exec dbms_preprocessor.print_post_processed_source ( -     
    object_type => 'procedure', -
    schema_name => 'myschema',  -
    object_name => 'cctest');

procedure cctest as
var1 binary_float;
begin
var1 := 1.23E+004;
end cctest;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589255) от участника [@pifor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10726850/pifor)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Не всегда условная компиляция возможна, например, значение условия вычисляется и на момент компиляции неизвестно. В этом случае можно воспользоваться условным оперетором `IF-ELSE`, чтобы поделить блок на подблоки, другими словами, на отдельные пространства имён.

Для избежания дубликации кода можно определить внутренние перегруженые функции. Принятые для этих целей в других ЯП синтктические конструкцие вида `template`, `generic`, в PL/SQL отсутствуют.

Примерно так это будет выглядеть:

```
create or replace procedure condtest (cond boolean) as
    function checkCondition return boolean is
    begin return cond; 
    end;
    function foo (par binary_float) return binary_float is
    begin dbms_output.put_line ('foo(float)='||par); return par; 
    end;
    function foo (par number) return number is
    begin dbms_output.put_line ('foo(number)='||par); return par;  
    end;
begin
    if checkCondition then <<cond_on>> 
        declare 
            var1 binary_float := 1.23E+004;
            res binary_float := foo (var1);       
        begin null;
        end;
    else <<cond_off>> 
        declare 
            var2 number := 999;
            res number := foo (var2);
        begin null;
        end;
    end if;
end condtest;
/

exec condtest (true)
foo(float)=1,23E+004

exec condtest (false)
foo(number)=999
```